# Google map using intent

Tags: android

I have 2 tabs in my application and one of that is for location Map.
So i have set that tab to start an activity to show the map.

code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I dont want to use googleAPi key and get the map, and i want to do it by intent.
But the problem here is, the map will be displayed over the complete screen and the tabs are not visible.

Is there a way i can display some button/ tab along with the map when the map is displayed using an intent ( not Mapactivity and setting APIkey )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (the Intent) starts Google Maps as a separate application. This is what Intents are supposed to do.

If you want Maps as a part of your application (visible within Tabs) you will need to use `MapActivity` or `MapView' (and provide the Maps key, of course). There is no way around it. For more details see http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Comment: I have a doubt here. If i use Apikey , i have to mention ( hardcode) it in the application , in my XML file.

Comment: -ctnd- , so when this application is installed on a another android device, will it work ? is the key not specific to the system where i generate it ?

Comment: Maps Key is specific to you, the developer. You must get it here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html

Comment: I had generated the key and i could get the map with the MApactivity. But my doubt is when this application is run on some other device, will it work with that key ?  if not how is it handled because any application that shows a location map never ask user to enter the key, it is handled by the application. i hope my question is clear. thanks a lot for your quick replies

Comment: I use this and it works. This is a developer key not a user's key. Google wants to know which apps/developers use their API, and that they accepted the license terms.